# How to prove this statement of big o notation? Proof

Tags: big-o

How to prove this :

3n^2 + 6n is O(n2)

Do i have to choose 6n as a constant ?

Comment: The general rule for big-O is that you take the portion of the term that grows quickest and that becomes the big-O value. n^2 will grow FAR quicker than 6n, so whatever you're analyzing will have O(n^2) performance. e.g. if n = 1,000,000, n^2 = 1,000,000,000,000 and 6n = 6,000,000 (or basically nothing in the bigger picture).

Comment: If this is an assignment (which it looks like) you should tag it as this.

Comment: Also, in either case, you might want to look up the corresponding Wikipedia page before asking here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that you need to show that there exist M and x0 for which |3x^2 + 6x| <= M|x^2| for all x > x0

Comment: You're mixing `n`'s and `x`'s :)

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde oops... you're absolutely right.